# Android : Setting controls as static good idea?

Tags: android, static

Just getting opinions here. My app has a toolbar below that are tabs. In the toolbar, there is a SAVE button where I want it to be visible ONLY when certain tabs are in "focus". I accomplished this by setting the menu item to static in the main activity and setting it to visible when the fragment is in "focus". Any downside to doing it like that? Will this cause large overheads?

Comment: What do you mean by "by setting the menu item to static"? Are you actually holding a reference to a `MenuItem` as a static field?

Comment: Why do you need it to be static?

Comment: Yes. Code is like  public static MenuItem actionBtn; So I can reference it from a fragment. Bad idea?